# Python: 64 bit version for Django for Mac?

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, mysql, python

I upgraded Python on Snow Leopard which broke Django.

So I went back to version 2.6, but now I can't seem to get MySQL db running because now I am running a 32 bit version of Python.

I would like to get a version of Python that works with my install of mod_wsgi AND will work with MySQLdb...I take it I need to go to a 64 bit version?

Note: I don't think I uninstalled the original version, but I'm not sure how to go back to it.

when I

```
cd /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/
```

I see:

```
2.6 3.2 Current
```

and when I type

```
python
```

I get:

```
Python 2.6.6 (r266:84374, Aug 31 2010, 11:00:51) 
[GCC 4.0.1 (Apple Inc. build 5493)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

But when I type

```
>>> import platform
>>> platform.architecture()
```

I get:

('32bit', '')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best bet is to build mod_wsgi and MySQLdb using the 64-bit python that you have.

The usual process is to download the code, cd into its directory and then:

```
python setup.py build
python setup.py install
```

(sudo may be required)